UI alignment not looks good and is shows dots, how can I fix it
I am trying to achieve the one design that is already completed using UIKit.
The same approach is followed to complete it, but the output does not look good.
Please find my code below:
    struct LoanHistoryView: View {
    let listContorller = LoanHistoryController()

    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView {
             List{

                 ForEach(listContorller.listOfValues, id: \.self){text in
                     HistoryContentView()
                         .background(Color.white)
                 }
                 .cornerRadius(10)
                 .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                 .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
             }
             .background(.green.opacity(0.6))
             .listStyle(.plain)
             .navigationTitle("LOAN HISTORY")

        }

    }
}




 struct HistoryContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

       VStack {
            HStack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("KW123456789066788")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                    Text("KARTHI | 7502875893")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Image(systemName: "menucard")
                        Text("REPORT")
                    }
                    VStack{
                        Image(systemName: "menucard")
                        Text("DOCUMENTS")
                    }
                    VStack{
                        Image(systemName: "menucard")
                        Text("CONTACT")
                    }
                }
            }
           VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
               Divider()
                   .frame(height: 1)
               .background(.gray)
               HStack(){
                   Text("HYNDAI CRETA 1.5 - CHENNAI")
                       .foregroundColor(.black)
                   Spacer()
                   Text("NEW-PRIVATE")
                       .foregroundColor(.cyan)
               }
               HStack(){
                   VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0){
                       Text("REGNO")
                       Text("TN09CQ0925")
                           .bold()
                   }
                   Spacer()
                   VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0){
                       Text("TENURE")
                       Text("60 MONTHS")
                           .bold()
                   }
                   Spacer()
                   VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0){
                       Text("EMI")
                       Text("23456")
                           .bold()
                   }
                   Spacer()
                   VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0){
                       Text("LOAN AMOUNT")
                       Text("3446667")
                           .bold()
                   }
               }.foregroundColor(.black)

               HStack(){
                   VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0){
                       Text("DEALER")
                       Text("KUWY001")
                           .bold()
                   }
                   VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0){
                       Text("LOS NUMBER")
                       Text("5678JKSKS888")
                           .bold()
                   }
                   Spacer()

               }.foregroundColor(.black)
               HStack {
                   VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0){
                       Text("AXIS BANK")
                       Text("TEST CASE REJECED BY KAMS")
                           .foregroundColor(.red)
                   }
                   Spacer()
               }
               VStack{
                   HStack {
                       Spacer()
                       Text("22-04-2024")
                   }
                   HStack {
                       Spacer()
                       Button(action: {
                           // Button action
                       }) {
                           Text("HELP")
                               .foregroundColor(.blue)
                               .underline()
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           Spacer()
       }
        
       .padding(10)

//       .scaledToFit()
//       .padding(.all, 5)

//        HStack {
//            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
//                Text("KW123456789066788")
//                    .foregroundColor(.red)
//                    .font(.title3)
//                Text("KARTHIKEYAN | 7502875893")
//                    .foregroundColor(.black)
//                    .font(.title3)
//            }
//            Spacer()
//            Button(action: {
//                // Action for DOCUMENT button
//                print("DOCUMENT button tapped")
//            }) {
//                VStack {
//                    Image(systemName: "doc.text")
//                        .font(.title)
//                    Text("DOCUMENT")
//                        .foregroundColor(.black)
//                        .font(.title3)
//                }
//                .padding()
//            }
//
//            Button(action: {
//                // Action for OFFER button
//                print("OFFER button tapped")
//            }) {
//                VStack {
//                    Image(systemName: "indianrupeesign.arrow.circlepath")
//                        .font(.title)
//                    Text("OFFER")
//                        .foregroundColor(.black)
//                        .font(.title3)
//                }
//                .padding()
//            }
//            Button(action: {
//                // Action for CONTACT button
//                print("CONTACT button tapped")
//            }) {
//                VStack {
//                    Image(systemName: "phone.connection")
//                        .font(.title)
//                    Text("CONTACT")
//                        .foregroundColor(.black)
//                        .font(.title3)
//                }
//                .padding()
//            }
//
//        }.padding(.all, 20)
    }
}

Desired output:

Current Output:


Very confusing question, desired output contains one record but the actual output contains a list of records and those records aren't even close to the desired one. You can't expect us to understand your issue just from two, very different, images so you need to provide a better explanation of what is wrong.

I just tried the first row of Hstack, as you can see by the code. Why buttons look ugly? I will update my code..

You can check my updated question, Is there anyway to control the font size globally? Why does the button title go down?

@karthikeyan the default font for Text, as mentioned in the documentation, is Body. Did you change the font for your UIKit version?

Yes, I have adjusted manually, and here I have not set the font size. How do we make  UI look better? Do I have to set the font size for every page, or is there a way to handle it all in one place?

@karthikeyan you could add .font(.caption2) to HistoryContentView()

You can get closer to your desired output with a few small changes:
1. Scale the images to the required size
Something like:
Image(systemName: "menucard")
   .resizable()
   .scaledToFit()
   .frame(width: 30, height: 30)

2. Set a smaller overall font size and set the width to .compressed
VStack {
    // ...
}
.padding(10)
.font(.subheadline)
.fontWidth(.compressed)

You might want to apply the compressed font style more selectively instead (in other words, only apply it to selected parts of the content, where it is actually needed).
3. Use even smaller fonts for detail rows
For example, use .footnote or even .caption where a smaller font is needed.
4. Prevent text truncation where necessary
Text truncation (with ellipses) can be prevented by setting a line limit and then allowing the font to be scaled to fit in the space available. Taking the HStack with the icons as an example:
HStack{
    // ...
}
.font(.caption)
.allowsTightening(true)
.lineLimit(1)
.minimumScaleFactor(0.5)

5. Use a Grid for the detail rows
By using a Grid, the second row of detail can be brought into alignment with the first row of detail.

Use Grid as the outer container for the rows, like a VStack.
Replace the nested HStack with GridRow.
Apply .gridCellColumns(2) to content that should occupy a width of 2 cells.
Include the Divider() as the first grid row, as this forces the grid to use the full screen width.

6. Remove the last Spacer
This spacer was adding unnecessary space at the bottom.
Here is the fully-updated code:
VStack {
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("KW123456789066788")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            Text("KARTHI | 7502875893")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "menucard")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                Text("REPORT")
            }
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "menucard")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                Text("DOCUMENTS")
            }
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "menucard")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                Text("CONTACT")
            }
        }
        .font(.caption)
        .allowsTightening(true)
        .lineLimit(1)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    }
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Grid(alignment: .leading, verticalSpacing: 10) {
            Divider()
                .frame(height: 1)
                .background(.gray)
                .gridCellColumns(4)
            GridRow {
                Text("HYNDAI CRETA 1.5 - CHENNAI")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .gridCellColumns(3)
                Text("NEW-PRIVATE")
                    .foregroundColor(.cyan)
            }
            GridRow {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0) {
                    Text("REGNO")
                    Text("TN09CQ0925")
                        .bold()
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0) {
                    Text("TENURE")
                    Text("60 MONTHS")
                        .bold()
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0) {
                    Text("EMI")
                    Text("23456")
                        .bold()
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0) {
                    Text("LOAN AMOUNT")
                    Text("3446667")
                        .bold()
                }
            }
            GridRow {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0) {
                    Text("DEALER")
                    Text("KUWY001")
                        .bold()
                }
                .gridCellColumns(2)

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0) {
                    Text("LOS NUMBER")
                    Text("5678JKSKS888")
                        .bold()
                }
                .gridCellColumns(2)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.footnote)
        }
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0) {
                Text("AXIS BANK")
                Text("TEST CASE REJECED BY KAMS")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("22-04-2024")
            }
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    // Button action
                }) {
                    Text("HELP")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .underline()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
.padding(10)
.font(.subheadline)
.fontWidth(.compressed)

And here's how it looks:

If the text items were mixed case (instead of all uppercase) then it might be easier to read and you could probably take off the compressed font style in some places. Uppercase text requires more width than mixed case.

How about custom font? It's nice to know about the GridRow feature and font compression, but the UI seems compressed. Thank you very much for your help☺️☺️

Did I follow the procedure correctly? I see a lot of repetitive code and seems like a lot of code is for the UI alone

Which one is best, as @Carsten suggested, or your answer?

@karthikeyan I would prefer .fontWidth(.condensed) IMO it's more readable. You also could nest the HStack and VStack in another way to achieve the same layout, though Grid is better suited for alignment. As he mentioned you should precisely define layout to achieve the UIKit pendant

@karthikeyan I don't know if you saw the note at the end (after the screnshot), I added it in an edit. If you can get away from all-uppercase text then you can probably avoid compressed font in most cases (the labels for the images might still need it). Then I would suggest trying out different font sizes to see what fits and what looks good, using the techniques in point 4 to avoid truncation. Ps. Thanks for accepting the answer!

Thank you, @Carsten
More practice can help me avoid this issue in the future, and I need to practice writing less code.

@Carsten How to overlay the Trackloan button i tried using zstack with offset but goes inside the cell view

@BenzyNeez How to overlay the Trackloan button i tried using zstack with offset but goes inside the cell view

@karthikeyan I would suggest applying it to the outer VStack as .overlay(alignment: .bottom). If you add some bottom padding to the VStack before you add the overlay, the overlay will be over the padding -> no offset required.

@BenzyNeez I added it, but it is not same as the above image
.overlay(
GradientButtonView()
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.alignmentGuide(.bottom) { $0[.bottom]} // Align to the bottom of the VStack
//                                    .alignmentGuide(.top) { $0[.bottom] - 20 }
, alignment: .bottom
)

do you have skype id? Please share it, if you wish to help

@karthikeyan If you're having difficulties then I would suggest posting it as a new question. You only need to show a large empty container with the button at the bottom -> keep it simple so that anyone wanting to help can reproduce the issue.

@BenzyNeez Can you pls help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78338474/ui-alignment-split-views-into-4-part-and-align-subviews-in-it
am unable to find the help
