UI alignment: Split views into 4 part and align subviews in it
I am making view not scrollable by splitting it different parts, like 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1
Here, we are facing the issue while adding the subviews to each part.
The first view starts from the top, but actually we wanted it from below the navigation bar.
The second view goes up when we add the grid layouts.
Please check my result and code that i have tried so far.
struct HomePageView: View {
    // Sample data for grid cells
        let gridData = (0...8).map { "Item\($0)" }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack(spacing: 15) {
                    //Header section
                    CustomSectionView(content: {
                        TopHeaderView()
                    }, color: .blue)
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.1)

                    //Grid section
                    CustomSectionView(content: {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout(), spacing: 10) {
                            ForEach(gridData, id: \.self) { item in
                                GridCellView(content: item)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(.white)
                    }, color: .white)

                    .overlay{
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                            .opacity(0.6)
                    }
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.5)
                    .shadow(color: .black ,radius: 3)

                    CustomSectionView(content: {
                        Text("Bottom Content View")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }, color: .blue)
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.4)
//                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(.green.opacity(0.6))
                .navigationBarTitle("HOME PAGE")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // Set navigation bar title
            }

        }.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
    // Configure grid layout
        private func gridLayout() -> [GridItem] {
            Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10), count: 3)
        }

}
struct GridCellView: View {
    let content: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Image(.newCarGray)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            Text(content)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
        .font(.title3)
//        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 100)
//        ZStack {
//            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
//                .fill(Color.blue)
//                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 100)
//            Text(content)
//                .foregroundColor(.black)
//                .font(.headline)
//        }
    }
}
struct CustomSectionView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    let color: Color
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            color // Default background color (you can replace with any color)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            content()
        }
    }
}

struct TopHeaderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            VStack {
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
//                    .frame(height: geo.size.height * 0.1) // Adjust gradient height
                    .overlay{
                        HStack{
                            CircleProfileImage(img: .sea)
                            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                Text("Executive")
                                Text("Karthiekyan Selvam")
                            }.foregroundColor(.white)
                            Button(action: {
                                print("Edit tapped")
                            }) {
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "pencil")
                                }
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct CircleProfileImage: View {
    var img: ImageResource
    var body: some View {
        Image(img) // Load the image using the provided name
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50) // Set the size of the image
            .clipShape(Circle()) // Clip the image into a circle
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1)) // Add a white stroke around the circle
            .shadow(radius: 7)
    }
}
#Preview {
    HomePageView()
}



Here are two problems that you need to resolve:
1. The spacing of the VStack is not being considered.

Either, you need to make it spacing: 0
Or, you need to subtract the sum of the gaps from geometry.size.height.

2. The content of CustomSectionView does not fit inside the height it is being given.
This section is being given 0.5 of the total height, but that's not enough, so it's overflowing. If you add .clipped() as the last modifier (after the shadow)  then you will see how it gets trimmed. So you probably need to re-think the height fractions, or the actual content itself.
If you change it to 0.7, and then change the bottom section to 0.2, then it works better:


This sounds good, The content of CustomSectionView does not fit within the height it is given.

Can we define grid cell size based on its superview white shadow view size so view will adjust automatically to the all devices

@karthikeyan You could pass the height to CustomSectionView as a parameter, so it can decide how large to make the rows or even how many rows to show. Other options would be scaling the content, or scrolling the sub-content (even if you don't want the full page to scroll). It sounds like you need a design to work from. This should show the appearance on small, medium and large iPhones as well as on iPads (assuming you will be supporting use on iPads too).
